# How to get total count from one of the inner join queries?

Tags: mysql, join, select, left-join, inner-join

I have written the following MYSQL query and the The Mysql version is `8.0.18-commercial`

```
SELECT p.server, 'Type1' AS Check_Type, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(vmtable.res SEPARATOR ', ') AS result
FROM server p 
INNER JOIN truns t ON t.oq_id = p.oq_id
    AND t.id = (SELECT t2.id FROM truns t2 
                WHERE t2.oq_id = p.oq_id 
                order by t2.created_at desc limit 1 )
INNER JOIN qvuln_info vmtable ON vmtable.run_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN qvuln_info_data vmtableinfo ON vmtableinfo.qid = vmtable.qid   
WHERE p.server regexp 'server1'
GROUP BY p.server
```

I am getting output as:

```
Hostname   Check_Type  result
server1    Type_ABC    Result 1,Result 2,Result 3,Result 4
```

I want to add another column as `VulCount` at the top level and that value should come from one of the inner join queries:

```
SELECT t2.id 
FROM truns t2 
WHERE t2.oq_id = p.oq_id 
order by t2.created_at desc
```

The output should look as below:

```
Hostname   VulCount    Check_Type  result
server1    4            Type_ABC       Result 1,Result 2,Result 3,Result 4
```

Here, `4` is output of

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM truns t2 
WHERE t2.oq_id = p.oq_id 
order by t2.created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

@mealhour can't you just include the sub query like this:

```
SELECT p.server, 
       der.VulCount,
       'Type1' AS Check_Type, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(vmtable.res SEPARATOR ', ') AS result
FROM server p 
INNER JOIN truns t ON t.oq_id = p.oq_id
    AND t.id = (SELECT t2.id FROM truns t2 
                WHERE t2.oq_id = p.oq_id 
                order by t2.created_at desc limit 1 )
INNER JOIN qvuln_info vmtable ON vmtable.run_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN qvuln_info_data vmtableinfo ON vmtableinfo.qid = vmtable.qid 
JOIN (SELECT t2.oq_id, 
          count(t2.*) as VulCount
      FROM truns t2 
      GROUP BY t2.oq_id) AS der  
WHERE p.server regexp 'server1'
    AND der.oq_id = p.oq_id
GROUP BY p.server
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as VulCount             FROM truns t2 
      GROUP BY t2.oq_id) AS d' at line 53 0.078 sec`

Comment: @mealhour change `t2.*` to something that is unique per row to get you the count, most commonly that would be an `id` column. if you have a column that is unique like `id` change the `count(t2.*)` to `count(t2.id)`, that should do it for you